# Displaying Data in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-design, datagridview

I am storing students grades in a table as follow:

```
StudentID | CourseID | TermID | Grade
   1      |    1     |   1    |   10
   1      |    2     |   1    |   12
   1      |    3     |   1    |   9
   1      |    4     |   1    |   5
   1      |    5     |   1    |   19
   1      |    1     |   2    |   11
```

the first 3 columns are foreign keys.
I need to display this data in a DataGridView for a certain student, ex:

```
_____|Course1|Course2|Course3|
Term1|  10   |   15  |   24  |
Term2|  12   |   30  |   50  |
```

How can I achieve that? Should I change the data model?

**EDIT** Added some example data. 
The below query can work, but how can I :

- Replave the TermIDs with their corresponding Names in the result.
- Same for Courses IDs, with selecting all available courses instead of writing their IDs ([1], [2]...)

  SELECT *
  FROM
  (
  SELECT [Grade], [TermID], [CourseID]
  FROM Grades WHERE StudentID = 1
  ) AS source
  PIVOT
  (
      MAX([Grade])
      FOR [CourseID] IN ([1] , [2], [3], [20])
  ) as pivot

Comment: CREATE A DATASET TO GET ALL YOUR NEED DATA AND THEN BIND IT TO A DATAGRID CONTROL

Comment: are you like cross table

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please show your current DataGridView code, so people know where you are stuck at.

Comment: Fill a dataset using dataadapter, then put the DataGridView.Datasource=dataset.tables(0)

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind a DataTable to your DataGridView. And maybe you need to construct a pivot table with SQL.

```
SELECT [Term], [Course1], [Course2], [Course3]
FROM (SELECT * FROM [Grades]) AS [SourceTable]
PIVOT (MAX([Grade])
FOR [Term]
IN ([Course1], [Course2], [Course3]))
AS [PivotTable])
ORDER BY [Term] ASC
```

**EDIT** if you say the fields are foreign keys, you need to JOIN corresponding tables on them of course.